# Как выполнить ajax без асинхронности?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
let FILE_TARGETS     = "./scr/db.php";


class Targets {

    constructor() {
        this.targetsArray = [];
    }
    getRegisteredUsers(after) {
        let sendInfo = "action=getRegisteredTargets";

        $.ajax({
            url: FILE_TARGETS,
            type: "GET",
            data: sendInfo,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                this.targetsArray = data;
                after();
            }
        });
    }

    getTargetsArray() {
        this.getRegisteredUsers(function() {
            return this.targetsArray;
        });
    }
}
```

Пробовал, через вызов функции, внутри вызова ajax, но так ничего не получается.

Пытаюсь вывести массив данных, через console.dir

```
function AnalyserInit() {
    let targets = new Targets();
    console.dir(targets.getTargetsArray());
}
```

Массив, точно правильный приходит. Отлично выводится, если вывести внутри самого ajax.
А как мне его в отдельный массив в классе записать? И потом обращаться к нему?

Comment: Тут или await или then

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685249/jquery-performing-synchronous-ajax-requests